# I try get value from session , But?

Tags: javascript, session

I try get value from session 
`var obj = ${dropdownRespJSON};` --Works well
But some value have "CEO's Office, CEO-SVP, C-EX,...";

> Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Help me please, Thank.

Comment: `var obj = ${dropdownRespJSON}; --Works well` - what programming language is that?

Comment: Then dropdownRespJSON doesn't contain properly formatted JSON.